# jQuery select via data-type

Tags: jquery

Trying to set a value on an input box but only if it's inside a `td` where `data-type=2`

```
<td data-type="1"><input class="amount"></td>
<td data-type="2"><input class="amount"></td>
<td data-type="3"><input class="amount"></td>
```

```
var key = $(this).parent().data("type"); // equals 2
var value = $(this).parent().children(".amount").val();

$('td').attr("data-type", key).children(".amount").val(value );
```

The `.attr` seems to be the problem, how can I select only the .amount that are inside a data-type with a value of 2?

Comment: When you pass `.attr()` two arguments, it *sets* the attribute. In your example you would be *setting* the `data-type` of each `<td>` to `key`. [x](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

Comment: I'm confused. `this` appears to refer to the input already, and it sounds like you're trying to set `this.value = this.value`

Comment: There's columns of each so I'm trying to repeat the top row downwards, works in practise but the example isn't big enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute selector:

```
$('td[data-type=' + key + ']').children(".amount").val(value );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```
$('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('type') == key;
}).find('.amount').val(value);
```

Although it's more verbose, this method will be quicker than the attribute selector.

Comment: @PedroEstrada that case is not the same as this. Check this one. The method used above is the green bar in the graphs: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-filter/5